# Windows 8 sign in error code: 0x80070426

Tags: windows-8

while switching or creating a new user account on Windows 8 it is unable to sign in.
Windows 8 sign in error code: 0x80070426. Tried to switch user with other account still same error. How to fix it

Comment: Looking up the error code, 0x80070426 - ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE. I realize that does not help even a little but at least it's a thing. Do you know of any services that were recently disabled? Also check the event logs.

Comment: No i haven't disabled any services and checked under msconfig all essential services are running fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and just solved it now.  Go to Windows services (Win+R) then type 'services.msc'.  Look for 'Microsoft Account sign-in assistant' and check if it is activated or not.  If it isn't started, double click it and then set it to start up automatically.  Restart the computer and see if it works - did for me.  Hope this is useful!