# Cannot activate Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I bought a Windows 7 Pro licence a couple of years ago. The installation got activated, of course. I've been working on the machine for some years. Of course, the licence has been used only on this one machine.

During the free upgrade offer, I did an inplace upgrade to Windows 10 Pro. The installation was activated, too. That's how it's supposed to be done. Once activated this way, it is valid to do a clean install of Windows 10 on the same machine.

The problem: After the clean Windows 10 reinstallation (version 10.0.14393) on the same machine without any hardware changed, it can not be activated. I'm getting the message that the activation servers cannot be reached. This can be read there for several days. I have a direct internet connection without a proxy. I've ensured that the firewall is not blocking anything related. In the event log, I can find the error number 0x80070426: The service cannot be started. I'm an experienced developer. I was not able to find out which service. All deactivated services are unrelated. The activation trouble shooter does not work because of the same error 0x80070426.

There is the slmgr.vb script to manage licences. Using "slmgr /ato" returns the same error. Starting the script (to be exact: cscript.exe executing the vb script) from within WinDbg shows a different behavior: Now WmiPrvSE is started, it connects to the internet and finally tells me that the product key is blocked. I do not know why. I think I did everything right. The only "helpful" answer I was able to find, was doing the whole process again, starting with the installation of Windows 7. For sure, I will not do this as it will take me several days again (yes, it does). Other reports of the problem were different as to at least one of the preconditions weren't met.

I'm also aware of this: 
[How to troubleshoot Product Activation in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-troubleshoot-product-activation-in-windows/33f31475-93b3-4d1c-812f-4b21fbd807a7)

Comment: I think you can call Microsoft and they will walk you through activating the license via phone, they give you a code to input and it verifies it (useful for offline activation) Maybe also check you windows 10 iso/dvd/exe?

Comment: _'the product key is blocked'_ - can you exclude the possibility that your key is used by someone else? I wouldn't know where you store your license key, but a quick cell phone picture of the key would enable someone else to use it; or you borrowed the DVD to someone or such. Just as a potential reason.

Comment: The small box was closed and undamaged when I opened it. Nobody had ever access to the box or the product key. The machine has always been malware free.

Comment: try calling Microsoft as @JCTechie suggested

Comment: "All deactivated services are unrelated"  Is the Software Protection service enabled (set to Delayed Automatic Start)? if you set _all_ the services back to [their defaults](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/), does it behave any different?

Comment: All services are at their defaults. Those that are deactivated were deactivated since installation. The startup mode of the Software Protection service is automatic. The LicenseManager and ClipSVC services are running. Finally the connection worked, so the blocked key is the problem now. I'm wondering why. I will consider activating by phone but this should not be necessary if one did everything right - I think I did.

Comment: @CryGuy - 0x80070426 is a service error.  This isn't a case of you doing something wrong, or the license key not being accepted, your system isn't even attempting to activate.  So you have two choice determine the reason the service is not starting or activate by phone.

Comment: [Windows 8 sign in error code: 0x80070426](https://superuser.com/questions/581633/windows-8-sign-in-error-code-0x80070426), [Error Code: “Microsoft Security Client” appears when I log in to my windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1151075/error-code-microsoft-security-client-appears-when-i-log-in-to-my-windows-10)

Comment: The current Windows 10 installers (all versions of the Windows 10 installation after and including 1511) will accept your Windows 7 license.  However, your Windows 7 license is not required, since you already installed and activated Windows 10 on the machine.  This means for all future instances of a Windows 10 installation on this specific machine it will automatically activated.  Do not spend any time installing Windows 7 and attempt to upgrade to Windows 10 or inputing your Windows 7 key, those are workarounds, to your current problem and are NOT actual solutions to it.

Comment: You can go ahead and disregard ALL threads from before July 2016 with regards to Windows 10, ALL threads from before July 2016, DO NOT apply to the current build of Windows 10.  You need to focus your attention on current threads, DO NOT TRUST ANY information about Insider Preview builds from before July 2016 as most of that information is currently wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you installed Windows 10 as an upgrade and then tried to install Windows 10 on the same machine as a clean install.

If you did not [deactivate the key or deactivate the installation](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/deactivate-uninstall-windows-product-key) before you did the clean install it will still be registered as in use. (Normally this shouldn't be a problem as the machine's fingerprint would be the same.)

In this situation, you'd need to call to get the key activated for your current installation. (This will also deactivate it for any previous installations.)

Comment: I've "clean installed" quite a few Windows 10's that were originally upgraded from Windows 8 or 7, and never had to "Deactivate" them first...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 As I said, this is usually not a problem. Regardless, in this particular case you are clearly unable to activate the clean install. Afaik, the only solution for that is to call for activation. I've had to do this on occasion and, aside from the wait times, the process was pretty painless.

Comment: You're confusing me with OP. I would have called MS to help with activation over the phone long before I came here for help. ;)  I'm simply suggesting that I've NEVER had to "deactivate" a copy of Windows for the sake of reinstall, ever.   That doesn't mean I've never had to call MS to get an activation to work properly tho. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ah, apologies. Yeah, I've never actually deactivated an installation myself, either. By the time I realize I probably should have, it's too late. Backups or YOLO? =P

Comment: @Ouroborus It seems that you used to be able to do that, and still can, but nowadays when you install the key on a new computer it just deactivates on the old one.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't follow the discussion as I've spent my time reinstalling Windows 10 (not 7) again exactly like I did  before. Activation worked this time. Very funny. ^^